# PC can't be made to automatically boot from the SSD anymore

Tags: boot, ssd

I have a dated gaming PC but it's still serving me well (i5 2500k, 970 GTX, Samsung 850 SSD, Asrock P67 Extreme 4 mobo).

Unfortunately, since yesterday, the PC has stopped automatically booting from the SSD. When I go to my BIOS setup, I can't select the SSD to add it to the boot order. However, when I exit the BIOS setup and go to the boot menu instead, I can select the SSD there and the PC boots just fine.

What can be causing this issue?

Comment: I'll give you two things to try: 1. Figure out specifically which harddrive it's trying to boot from, then plug your SSD into that one's specific slot (basically switch the cables).  2. Unplug all your other harddrives except for the SSD, and see if you can set the SSD as the default boot device in BIOS then (when it's the ONLY harddrive plugged in).

Comment: On which harddrive is your /boot partition?

Comment: @J0hn Great advice and that actually solved it ... I just switched the cables and now it's booting normally again. Still confused why it happened. I assumed if a cable was broken I wouldn't be able to boot from my ssd at all, but I was able to. Thanks for the help!